# Remove or override hover text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, unbind

I use a follower counter script on my blog and I was experimenting to see if I could hide it so only I knew it was there. (You have to keep it in the description for it to work.)

I can't read javascript, while I can CSS and HTML (to a certain degree). I'm dealing with a javascript code here that I'd like to disable a hover effect for.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var fhsf = document.createElement('script');
  fhsf.src = "//tc.freehostedscripts.net/tcounter.php?url=xxx.tumblr.com&name=⋆&a=1";
  document.head.appendChild(fhsf);
  document.write("<span id='f_counter'></span>");
</script>
```

I googled and ended up with `$.unbind('hover');` which I inserted but then it made the links unclickable. Is there any way to keep the link clickable while removing the hover?

Comment: Do you want to hide the counter script or are you asking something about a hover or something? Based on the information in your question, you've only given us enough to show you how to hide it. If you have a question about a hover effect, you need to include the relevant html and the code that's causing the hover. We can't help if we can't see the code or the problem... we're not mind readers :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see how that would be difficult to understand. Basically when you hover over the link,  there's a popup hover thing that says so-and-so has this many followers. Which is what I'd like to remove.  Although I know it's referencing a document that has all the code in it, I was just wondering if there was anything in the script we're given here to disable the hover.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant information its difficult to know, you'll need to update your question to include the HTML that's generated by the script and the part of the js code that triggers the hover so we can take a look ans see what can be done.

Comment: I believe this would be the generated html

`<a href="http://freehostedscripts.net/fc.php?id=aW5jaWRpZW0udHVtYmxyLmNvbXw3MzYyMjF8MXwx" target="_blank" title="xxx.tumblr.com has a total of xxx followers!" class="">xxx ⋆</a>`

Comment: You should update your question instead of adding code to comments, so that everyone can see it - people don't always read comments :). We also need to see the javascript that's triggering the hover, because thats what we need to target. Is there definitely a js hover effect, and it's not just the default HTML title that appears on hovering over any element with a title?

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that in future. It turns out it's the coding for the blog itself that had a styled tooltip. If I just remove the tooltip code, no hovers will show up on the blog whatsoever. 
I'll explore a bit more later to see if I can figure out a way to disable the tooltip code only for the blog's description. Otherwise, I'm pretty happy. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Can you include the tooltip code here? It should be relatively easy for us to help you fix that once you know where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Even if an element is added using javascript, you can still target it using CSS.

For example, the javascript looks like it is inserting an element `<span id='f_counter'></span>` into your page, so to hide the counter script, just hide it with a CSS rule:

```
#f_counter { 
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: if you take a look at the 'src' link it's actually inserting an anchor <a>

Comment: @RobyRodriguez There's no mention of any anchor in the question. Its not up to us to go through external code to figure out what the OP wants. The question asked about hiding the counter, and that is the only possible answer based on the specific information given - if they need something else, they must include the relevant information in their question as per the Stack Overflow guidelines.